# how to install check_db2 plugin

Tags: nagios

I am trying to install check_db2 plugin in /usr/lib/nagios/plugins.

Hownloaded tar file & extracted then moved check_db2_health.pl file under /usr/lib/nagios/plugins.

Unable to find help parameters for the plugin as shown in the image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your 'make' command failed, so the 'ckeck_db2_health.pl' you found is not a valid Perl script.  If you run 'perl -wc check_db2_health.pl', you should see a line that says 'check_db2_health.pl syntax OK', if not, something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the 'check_db2_health.pl' file (read the README file!).  Instead use the file called 'check_db2_health' (no .pl extension).  Copy that file into your plugins folder.  You should be able to run:

```
./check_db2_health --help
```

And see the proper help output.  Notice there is no .pl extension.